# Listar x cantidad de carpetas en php

Tags: php

debo listar x cantidad de carpetas que se encuentran en una ruta, he intentado con:

```
$segmento = 10;
if ($handler = opendir($rutaOrigen)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handler))) {
        echo "$file<br>";
    }
}
closedir($handler);
```

y he intentado colocarlo en un ciclo for para que solo me liste las primeras 10 carpetas, pero no me ha generado resultados, intente cambiar el while por un for tambien, pero solo logre que se repitiera la cantidad, tambien intente con la funcion scandir y tampoco logre hacerlo, el resultado es que me repite la cantidad de archivos las veces que itera el ciclo for, y tengo mas de 1 millon de archivos

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te sale algo en los logs de PHP? Lo que mencionas del ciclo for, no es claro el resultado que tuviste. "no logré hacerlo" no es muy diciente; procura indicar qué errores encuentras (página en blanco, salió algo en los logs del servidor: xyz)

Comment: Como ya han mencionado, podrías añadir que errores te están dando para poder ayudar mejor. Una alternativa, podrías probar y crear tu propio contador, una forma muy simple, antes de tu línea ```while``` inicias ```$i=1;``` y luego en dentro de tu ```while``` podrías comprobar tu contador así ```if ($i <= $segmento) { echo "$file<br>"; }  $i++;``` y luego  lo vas incrementando el contador ```$i++;``` dentro de tu ```while```.

Comment: El problema es que es una carpeta que tiene mas de 1 millon de archivos, por eso solo necesito ver los primeros 10  o 100, al iterar con un for me repite todo el listado la cantidad del for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Has probado así?

```
$segmento = 10;
if ($handler = opendir($rutaOrigen)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handler)) and $segmento--) {
        echo "$file<br>";
    }
}
closedir($handler);
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias fue la solucion definitiva